# Flutter - function to create user using firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm learning flutter on my own, and I'm using firebase on a small project. I'm in the stage of working with login and registrations, so I needed to use a plugin called **firebase_auth: ^ 0.20.0 + 1**.
However, I have reached a point in my code where one occurs, and I don't know what can cause it.
When I create the user, I indicate an email and a password in **.createUserWithEmailAndPassword**, if it works it should return a function to indicate success in the creation, there is no error log because I did not complete the code and performed this step, however the error is in the syntax that I'm using in this function, it doesn't seem to be in accordance with the syntax of firebase, I must be doing something wrong. He says these lines are wrong **.then ((user) {firebaseUser = user;**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserModel extends Model {
  //usuario atual

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
  Map<String, dynamic> userData = Map();

  bool isLoading = false;
  void signUp(Map<String, dynamic> userData, String pass, VoidCallback onSucess,
      VoidCallback onFail) {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: userData["email"], password: pass)
        .then((user) async{
      firebaseUser = user;

      onSucess();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((e) {
      onFail();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void signIn() async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void recoverPass() {}

  //bool isLoggedIn() {}
}

class FirebaseUser {}
```

Comment: Although the `.then` will do the job, its better to use async and await inside a try catch block to avoid callback hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html) creates a user and returns a `Future<UserCredential>`.

In the `then` (which takes care of the `Future` part of this result), you assign the [`UserCredential`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) to your `firebaseUser` variable, which is defined as `FirebaseUser firebaseUser`. And the error message tell you that `FirebaseUser` and `UserCredential` are not compatible types.

To get the `FirebaseUser` from the `UserCredential`, use:

```
.then((credentials) async{
    firebaseUser = credentials.user;
```

Depending on the version of the `firebase_auth` plugin you use, you might need to declare `firebaseUser` as:

```
User firebaseUser
```

That is the correct type in the latest version of the FlutterFire libraries, while older builds had it as `FirebaseUser`.

I've linked the relevant reference documentation above, as I find that most helpful when troubleshooting these types of problems. I highly recommend keeping them open while you're learning about the API.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the change worked perfectly.